# Data tabels in react native

Tags: react-native, datatables

Can someone please suggest me any data table library in react native which can add rows dynamically and having editable cells. I am done searching in google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-data-table`

This library is created using the `React` and `RealmJS` DB on `JSX`.

useful links:
**[about react-native-data-table](https://github.com/sussol/react-native-data-table)**

OR

You can use `react-native-paper`

**Example**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataTable } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DataTable>
        <DataTable.Header>
          <DataTable.Title>Dessert</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title numeric>Calories</DataTable.Title>
          <DataTable.Title numeric>Fat</DataTable.Title>
        </DataTable.Header>

        <DataTable.Row>
          <DataTable.Cell>Frozen yogurt</DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell numeric>159</DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell numeric>6.0</DataTable.Cell>
        </DataTable.Row>

        <DataTable.Row>
          <DataTable.Cell>Ice cream sandwich</DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell numeric>237</DataTable.Cell>
          <DataTable.Cell numeric>8.0</DataTable.Cell>
        </DataTable.Row>

        <DataTable.Pagination
          page={1}
          numberOfPages={3}
          onPageChange={(page) => { console.log(page); }}
          label="1-2 of 6"
        />
      </DataTable>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks hong. But user must add rows dynamically and must edit cells is this available in react native.

Comment: @Bharath Set the value of Textinput or select box to the row value of the module.